# Django annotate field value from external dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-orm, keyerror, django-annotate

Lets say I have a following dict:

```
schools_dict = {
   '1': {'points': 10},
   '2': {'points': 14},
   '3': {'points': 5},
}
```

And how can I put these values into my queryset using annotate?
I would like to do smth like this, but its not working

```
schools = SchoolsExam.objects.all()
queryset = schools.annotate(
    total_point = schools_dict[F('school__school_id')]['points']
)
```

Models:

```
class SchoolsExam(Model):
    school = ForeignKey('School', on_delete=models.CASCADE),

class School(Model):
    school_id = CharField(),
```

This code gives me an error `KeyError: F(school__school_id)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not work with `F` objects in a lookup, since a dictionary does not "understand" `F`-objects.

You can translate this to a [*conditional expression* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

schools = SchoolsExam.objects.annotate(
    total_point=Case(
        *[
            When(school__school_id=school_id, then=Value(v['points']))
            for school_id, v in school_dict.items()
        ]
    )
)
```

This will thus "unwind" the dictionary into `CASE WHEN school_id=1 THEN 10 WHEN school_id=2 THEN 14 WHEN school_id=3 THEN 5`.

However using data in a dictionary often does not make much sense: usually you store this in a table and perform a JOIN.