# How to insert a value from a dict in a django annotation using each id from queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a simple dict containing ids with values associated like: `{1:True, 2:False}`

My model:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

I also have a queryset that have the same ids listed above in an atribute named `user_id`, but I need to add a new field to my objects on queryset with the values from my dict.
Lets suppose the field I want to add is called `is_admin`, so I need to create a field on the object with id `1` on my queryset with the value `True`.

What I tried to do is:

```py
my_dict= {1:True, 2:False}

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    is_admin=Value(my_dict.get(F("user_id")), output_field=BooleanField())
)
```

But what happen is that I'm receiving `null` on `is_admin`. I tried to do the code below and it works:

```py
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    is_admin=Value(my_dict.get(1), output_field=BooleanField())
)
```

So I think is something wrong with my use of F expression. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you share your model?

Comment: @ruddra I added now

Comment: Does it help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74969840/django-annotate-field-value-from-external-dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not ok to mix non-trivial python code into the query expression, beacause it needs to be translated to raw SQL.

I suggest setting this property after you get the data from DB. Something like this:

```
results = list(queryset)
for r in results:
  r.is_admin = my_dict.get(r.id, False)
```

Other alternatives, if you want to use this in multiple places:

1. create new `@property def is_admin(self): return my_dict.get(self.id, False)`
2. add it as a new field for your model

Comment: This might be of consideration, but depending on the model for 'Value', it should accept a boolean in sql just fine. Creating that object from an object of none will make a null value however.

Comment: But I do not think the query expression will work for this: `my_dict.get(F("user_id"))`. Django would need to somehow translate a python method call to SQL.

Comment: After he creates the object he has to call 'is_admin.save()' Creating objects[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the expression F is used to modify strings while your dictionary keys are integer values. Modify the `my_dict.get()` value by casting it to an integer using `int()`

```
>>> newString = f"{user_id}"
>>> newString
'2'
>>> print(my_dict.get(newString))
None
>>> newInt = int(newString)
>>> print(my_dict.get(newInt))
False
```